# Additional keybinding combination to copy text to clipboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like know, how to make *copy to clipboard* work not only with the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> key-combination but also using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> for instance.

How do I do that?

Comment: `Ctrl`+`Ins` copies to the primary selection. Why would you want to override that?

Comment: I need it for certain purposes. Any idea of how to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify? I see no reason why you would want to override the primary selection. You can easily use `Shift`+`Ins` to paste from it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Some other application was overriding it.. Sorry.

Comment: @HalosGhost What about other key-combination? Like `Ctrl+End`, just to learn. Any idea?